# Include class name when using Doctrine 2 array hydration

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In Doctrine 2 is there a way to get the array hydration mode to include the class name of the relevant entity in the output, so instead of:

```
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'test',
    // ...
);
```

You get:

```
array(
    '__class' => 'MyProject\MyClass',
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'test',
    // ...
);
```

I know the `Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ArrayHydrator` class has access to the relevant information, but I'm trying to work out if this can be done without re-implementing the entire `ArrayHydrator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So creating a custom hydrator that extends `ArrayHydrator` and overriding the `gatherRowData` method with this is one potential solution:

```
protected function gatherRowData(array $data, array &$id, array &$nonemptyComponents)
{
    $rowData = parent::gatherRowData($data, $id, $nonemptyComponents);

    foreach ($rowData['data'] as $dqlAlias => $data) {
        $class = $this->_rsm->aliasMap[$dqlAlias];
        $meta  = $this->getClassMetadata($class);
        if ($meta->discriminatorMap) {
            $class = $meta->discriminatorMap[$data[$meta->discriminatorColumn['name']]];
        }
        $rowData['data'][$dqlAlias]['__CLASS__'] = $class;
    }

    return $rowData;
}
```

Be interested to know if there's a better way?